# Display a string item from a list without repetitions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a little quiz game with multiple choices for practicing. Each answer button has a random item taken from a string list. I mean, the list contains elements and with this script I "paste" a random string element from that list in the UI text box to show an answer:

```
    public Text answerText;

    [SerializeField]
    private int randomAnswerIndex;

    void Start () {
        randomAnswerIndex = Random.Range(0, languageAnswers.Count);
        answerText.text = languageAnswers[randomAnswerIndex];

    }
```

Each answer button has this script referenced, but I don't know how to avoid that an item text from the list shows twice, i.e., the word "English" in two different buttons at the same time. How can I solve it? If it's with an "if" statement, how can I access to the different button texts from the script? Thanks!

Comment: Generate all the possibilities, then shuffle them.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a string at the selected index each time a string was selected for an answerText.

Make sure to do a copy to don't loose the inital list of strings in case of reuse and that all scripts will take the same list.

```
languageAnswers.Remove(randomAnswerIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work, because the script acts on each button independently of the others. Perhaps I should compare the text of each respective button before it put a string in the text box, but I don't know how to call them specifically.